# Get customer attribute value

Tags: magento2

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

It returns all the data about the customer with my custom attribute, but how to get this attribute, I tried many options, but give an error

[image]

using event adminhtml_customer_save_after

Comment: Is this custom attribute, right?

Comment: Dhiren Vasoya ,  yes

Comment: Does you are able to access this customer attribute any where into system when you load that customer?

Comment: I have not tried

Comment: I want to get it and save it in my custom table during the adminhtml_customer_save_after event

Comment: that is, when they click on the save customer button

Comment: First confirm that you are able to access that attribute when customer is load? you can test it by scritp from magento root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89436/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-robinio-tor).

Comment: You can use like $this->$customer->getData('suspend_customer');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using [**extension attribute**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html)  concept then you can get this custom field value by

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); 
$suspend_customerValue= $customer->getCustomAttribute('suspend_customer')
            ? $customer->getCustomAttribute('suspend_customer')->getValue()
            :'';
```